# Increase heap space in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, heap-memory

I am running Eclipse Kepler. Just downloaded it. I'm trying to get an Android application working (hich I have done in the past). But now when I run it, I get "Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded".

I don't have an eclipse.ini file. I've looked for it, in the folder where all my eclipse stuff was extracted to. And when I go to run->run configurations, there is no arguments tab for me to tell Eclipse to use more heap space. (There is no arguments tab for Android run configurations.)

How do I fix this?

Edit: here is my config.ini file: http://textuploader.com/1j3b
Should I be worried that it looks nothing like anyone else's ini file?

Comment: It's strange that you don't have an eclipse.ini or equivalent in the root of the installation. Have you tried to create it?
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Comment: what is the equivalent?

Comment: I said that because my current installation calls it "zend-eclipse-php.ini". I thought you could have something similiar there.

Comment: Does confg.ini the equivalent? And if so, is it normal for it to say nothing about memory size?

Comment: It has chances to be. Here a paste of mine, from the PHP version from Zend: http://textuploader.com/1j3w

Comment: here's mine. http://textuploader.com/1j3b It looks nothing like yours.

Comment: try to create one like the first link I sent you and see if it work

Comment: How? Why would I expect your ini file to work on my computer?

Comment: Not mine. This one: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Comment: Do I add this to top? Do I erase the other stuff in my config.ini file?

Comment: *"Should I be worried that it looks nothing like anyone else's ini file?"* - erm ... yes.  How did you create your Eclipse installation?  If you created it in the normal way (download from Eclipse site, unpack archive) there **should** be an `eclipse.ini` file in the installation directory.  If not, it suggests that something has trashed your installation.  Reinstall it, and see if that helps.

Comment: If you have the installation in a read only location the `eclipse.ini` will be in a separate location in your home directory.